# Explicit interface implementation in php

Tags: php, interface

Since I'm a C#-/.NET-guy, I'm used to *explicit interface implementations* - like so:

```
public interface IBar
{
    bool Bacon();
}

public class Foo : IBar
{
    bool IBar.Bacon() {}
}
```

**Question:**

Is this possible to do in php?

**Edit:**

To clarify, this is *implicit* (while what I want, and what is in the above example, is *explicit*):

```
public class Foo : IBar
{
    bool Bacon() {}
}
```

Comment: You mean something like this? http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php

Comment: The only thing I have found there is *implicit* implementations. Or have I missed something?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that there's some kind of distinction. I hope this is only .NET-related stuff, otherwise I would feel really stupid now!

Comment: Oh, no worry. Think about it this way: If I were to inherit from two interfaces that shared a common signature, there would be a problem if I invoked the signature without casting to the interface.

Comment: Alright, I see :) Well, I don't know if this is *exactly* what you're looking for (or if I really got it right), but I use to work around things like that with *namespaces* (http://de2.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php). So if you put both interfaces in different namespaces, you can still use them both in one place, explicitly addressing them throught their namespaces. But since C# is completely based on namespaces, I guess this is not quite what you're looking for... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP supports interfaces, so yes it is possible: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php

PHP does not distinguish between implicit and explicit implementations.

Comment: There is no information whatsoever about *explicit* implementations in the link you provided.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a PHP guy (.NET days long past), and there is no distinction in the PHP world, so I assumed you ware just looking for interfaces.

Comment: No worry. You say "there is no distinction", does that mean there is no way to implement a signature explicitly?

Comment: Just discovered there wasn't any accepted answers; Add that last comment to your answer and you'll have another answer to your rep :)